# Does higher retransmission time imply lesser chances of congestion?

Tags: congestion

I believe that with higher retransmission time value, the frequency at which retransmissions occur will reduce. And with less frequent retransmissions, the traffic will decrease. So with that logic, I believe that congestion will be decreased. Although the overall delay might increase but still, the contribution towards congestion will be less. So I wish to know whether my line of thought is correct.

Note : By 'higher' retransmission time value I do not wish to include infinitely high retransmission time value. To put it simply, as compared to regular retransmission time, say 2-3 minutes I wish to assume high retransmission time value as 10-12 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delayed retransmissions reduce the effectively used bandwidth, so congestion may be reduced. Just as well, the other participant might choose to enlarge their windows = increase their used bandwidth, so it may also have no overall effect.

Assuming TCP as transport-layer protocol, timeout-based retransmissions are triggered after *RTT + 4x(RTT variation)*. Several minutes would mean one hell of a round-trip time...

Comment: Can I ask the source for this information? It can help me to explore more.

Comment: For TCP you should start with [RFC 793](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc793).

Comment: And where should I head towards in order to explore congestion (not just in TCP but also also at the router level)?

Comment: Routers don't retransmit. Routers queue a few packets, then they drop excess. Using QoS policies you can control which packets they drop preferably, but that's it.